# Co-ordinates of a button in android

Tags: java, android

I have a button on screen, I want to get the x and y coordinates of that image, by using that image coordinates I need to move image,  help me needed, Thank you

Comment: use View.getLocationOnScreen()...

Comment: i tried for any default methods to get coordinates, but i didnt

Comment: oh... should have known. sorry

Comment: Thanks for responses, View.getLocationOnScreen() for this can you please give me example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
int[] loc = new int[2];
someView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
//loc[0] - x;
//loc[1] - y;
```

Comment: Thank you for valuable time, but eveytime am getting loc values 0,0

Answer (score 0):

You can get the real size and position in the onWindowFocusChanged method, here is where you put the code.